# Artificial intelligence beginner question

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I want to dive into AI topic. I'm specifically interested in multiagent systems. What resources, book, etc. can you recommend to get started, from the very beginning?  If that matters I'm a .NET developer.

Comment: This is far too general a question to be usefully answered here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the book I used at Uni :

[Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach (International Edition)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0130803022/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=finraddev-21&linkCode=as2&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=0130803022)

I found it to be excellent and easy to understand.

Comment: It's the first book that came to my mind too.  Especially good for investigating agent-based AI.

Answer (score 5):

You can check out my free [Multiagent Systems Textbook](http://multiagent.com/2010/02/multiagent-systems-textbook.html).

Answer (score 3):

I know of two books that are very good resources in multi-agent systems and provide algorithmic view of it:

[Multiagent Systems: Algorithmic, Game-Theoretic, and Logical Foundations(free download)](http://www.masfoundations.org/index.html)

[Fundamentals of Multiagent Systems with NetLogo Examples (free download)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.136.6670&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Two other books for anyone else that comes across this question:

[Essentials of Metaheuristics](http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/book/metaheuristics/) goes over many commonly used approaches in modern AI.

and

[Swarm Intelligence: From Natural to Artificial Systems](http://books.google.com/books?id=fcTcHvSsRMYC&dq=Swarm+Intelligence+From+Natural+to+Artificial+Systems&source=gbs_navlinks_s) a bit old, but good fundamentals of nature-inspired swarm techniques.